# How to select the first n rows in a C# datatable?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have extracted a data table from MS SQL and want to select the first n number of rows from this data table. I tried some other methods found on stackoverflow such as `AsEnumerate()` but it said that the extension does not exist. What other options do I have?

My datatable is 3 columns and about 250 rows.

```
tbl = db.GetDataTable(strSQL.ToString(), param);
param = null;
param = new IDbDataParameter[1];

if (rCount != 0)
{
    strSQL = null;
    strSQL = new StringBuilder();
    strSQL.Append("SELECT *");
    strSQL.Append(" FROM  " + Database + "..db" + DB_Com_Methods.WNLC());
    strSQL.Append(" where x in (");
    strSQL.Append("@y");
    strSQL.Append(")");
    strSQL.Append(" ORDER BY Date ASC ");
    param[0] = new SqlParameter("@y", z);
    tbl = db.GetDataTable(strSQL.ToString(), param);
}

return tbl;
```

Comment: I think it would be useful if you posted the code to request the data from the database.

Comment: Here you go @JonasH

Answer (score 2):

Add a [`TOP <number>`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_top.asp) statement to your sql query. I.e.

```
 strSQL.Append("SELECT TOP 10 *");
```

Answer (score 1):

you have 2 options. As suggested by @JonasH, use TOP in your query or you can use below method

```
var topRows = tbl .AsEnumerable().Take<DataRow>(2);//top 2
```